Does this follow from Everett's Many-Worlds?
My understanding from Many-Worlds primarily comes from Sean Carroll, and not from the original paper, however, it seems that this naturally follows from the loose interpretation.
As a preliminarily, my naive understanding of Many-Worlds is that the effectiveness of the wave function, whether it is actual real or just a math trick, might indicate that every possible measurement outcome exists in a different world. And that world is not just an experiment it's all of the environment around it as well. And Schrödinger's equation gives us a way to predict how the wave function changes over time, giving us a very loose sense in understanding how the worlds split.
I would like a clarification of Everett's interpretation on the following. If the wave function of a particle is very narrow (giving high certainty in it's position) does that mean that "most" of the worlds that split have that particle being measured near that peak? (Are there a continuous topology of worlds? Because the wave function is continuous and each possible open set of locations a particle can be measured in space has an associated probability from the wave function.)
My main query is this: If every possible world exists, and quantum probability simply emerges from the abundance or perhaps density of worlds according to the properties of the wave function/Schrödinger's equation, then there are still real worlds in which very unlikely events happen. For example, there is a world where every Stern-Gerlach experiment reads every spin of every particle in the same direction. There is also a world where this persists until the heat death of the universe. And there is also a world in which all of the events that "this" world happened exactly as we currently have experienced it and then tomorrow (relative to the reader reading this) every Stern-Gerlach experiment is constant for the rest of the universe's life. And in that universe, we developed quantum mechanics and learned to trust it and built technology around it. And then suddenly physics simply "broke" and never ever fixed itself again. And perhaps they would develop a completely accurate but "wrong" theory of physics for their world.
Does this thought experiment make sense in Everettian Many-Worlds? If so, what does it mean? Could that mean we should not trust our theories of the world as strong as we do? I know it is very "unlikely" that is the world we will appear to live in by tomorrow. Similar to how entropy is simply emergent from probability theory. We trust it in the limit. But we only have a sample of one in our case: the world we live in and the one "we" will continue to live in in the future.
(Unrelated: I just want to say how I appreciate how much people are more polite and civilized on this site and Math Stack Exchange compared to Stack Overflow. That place is a nightmare sometimes lol)

Yes, this is a consequence of MWI. But it is no different than some long chains of fair coin tosses, very unlikely ones, coming up all tails. Should this make us act differently than we otherwise would when betting on heads coming up? Obviously not. The tosses are independent just as the choice of a branch in MWI, we are not in any pre-existing 'world', it gets made probabilistically at each branching. Btw, Carroll has a blog post on the relation between the Born rule and decision-making under MWI.

You have rediscovered quantum Darwinism, which says (among other things) that the typical Stern-Gerlach experiment will have 50-50 outcomes, because those other outcomes are so much less likely. Note that the original formulation of quantum Darwinism is laden with metaphors from biology, but the core concept is straightforward: "survival of the fit" becomes "observation of the likely".

Also, some of your phrasing suggests that you're thinking of multiple worlds as physically extant, which is a common mistake for Everettians. Rather, the multiple worlds are virtual, like virtual particles; they are an artifact of the mathematical equations, not an observable property of physical reality.

A better way to think of many-worlds is that there aren't actually different universes splitting off all the time. Rather, there exists one universe and one universal wave function, which evolves over time but never collapses into a single "real" reality. The wave function isn't a probability distribution from which reality is sampled; the wave function is reality.  We just have a hard time picturing the entire wave function because our brains are a part of it, so we can't really view it from outside. (Disclaimer: I am not a physicist.)

As a first note, I would warn against the point of view that MWI can make testable predictions that contradict other interpretations of quantum mechanics. Even Max Tegmark has admitted that his ideas to test MWI, including the Quantum Immortality would similarly well work in Copenhagen interpretation. We are yet to see a single even thought experiment that would clearly distinguish different interpretations as long as they are based on Schroedinger's equation.
That said, it is often very useful to look at different thought experiments from the points of views of different interpretations and see that some things that have evident and logical manifestations in one interpretation, correspond to unevident and counter-intuitive phenomena in others. And finding these correspondencies.
The phenomenon you have described from the point of view of Many-World Interpretation, has a relatively less known name in the de Broglie-Bohm interpretation. It is called "Quantum Non-Equilibrium". It has been also argued as a thought experiment to test the de Broglie-Bohm interpretation and distinguish it from others, but as we can see, it has a corresponding prediction in MWI as well.
Specifically, Quantum Non-Equilibrium is a state where the Born rule is not obeyed. And infamous Quantum Immortality is also an example of a case of quantum non-equilibrium.
Conceptually, Quantum Non-Equilibrium is similar to thermodynamic non-equilibrium states, but its time of relaxation is much, much shorter (on the scale of , where ε is
the coarse-graining length that is used in comparing the coarse-grained non-equilibrium
and equilibrium distributions).

From a physicist's point of view: the many-worlds interpretation would suggest that, for a wave function that is "tight" in the sense of there being a small volume of state space whose integrated amplitude is much greater than that of the surrounding state space, across the extremely high-dimensional "world space", most worlds would have the particle represented by the wave function collapsing into a state within that small volume when the WF is observed.
Also, yes, what you propose is true: in the Everettian interpretation, there exist worlds where quantum "randomness" suddenly attains (or has always had) very strange properties, like all Stern-Gerlach experiments reporting the same spin for every particle, or everything being "normal" up to a certain point in time and then suddenly reporting only spin-up in any SG experiment, or the spins of the SG experiments encoding binary data which when decoded using ASCII or UTF-8/16 read intelligent human language that seems to indicate that a god is trying to communicate with us through quantum channels. In the Everettian interpretation, these are all components of the "world space".
Imagine each world as a set of "frames" that form a timeline, each frame an instantaneous representation of the quantum state of every particle in the entire Universe. For a frame to exist in the traditional sense and become part of reality, every particle in the Universe has to collapse into the exact quantum state that is prescribed by that frame. You can draw timelines by connecting decently-similar frames, but this isn't actually practical: the probability of the Universe collapsing into one frame is already astronomically small so as to be considered infinitesimal, and the probability that it collapses into an arbitrarily-long series of frames thus rounds to zero. What you could do instead is make the timeline "fuzzy"; a timeline then includes frames that are very similar to each other so, at the macroscale, the timeline isn't affected by a single photon polarizing spin-up or spin-down: a frame must deviate significantly from "normal" in order to be considered to be on a separate timeline.
The reason quantum physics doesn't break or start speaking perfect French or otherwise behave in an unexpected way is that some timelines are more difficult to stay on than others. Timelines that string together increasingly-improbable events, like a Stern-Gerlach experiment continuously reporting only spin-up particles, require that there be no significantly-more-probable timelines "near" it in world space, and because such an event is extremely improbable, there are always more-probable timelines near ones that contain such events. Thus, because it is astronomically-unlikely that the Universe remain on such a timeline, reality diverts to another more-probable one. It may be possible for reality to divert to a less-probable timeline, but staying on that timeline long enough to macroscopically affect the Universe is difficult because that improbable timeline is, well, improbable. At our ultra-fast timescale (compared to the quantum timescales), even if the Universe did divert to an improbable timeline for a moment, we would just see a series of spin-up particles on our Stern-Gerlach apparatus. Just a random string of 1s on a random binary number generator that happens to be a bit longer than normal.
In short, we can trust that our understandings of the Universe won't break down, even if we interpret quantum mechanics the Everettian way. For them to break down would require diverting onto a timeline with such low probability and surrounded by so many timelines with greater probability that and for long enough that the chance of it happening except by some weird divine intervention is essentially nil.

Maybe this is just a difficult subject, but having a hard time parsing out this answer. I think this is saying: The timeline/"many world" where things are "weird" requires a series of improbable events, and the sum collection of events is so improbable we won't encounter that in "our" world.

@BurnsBA Yes that is correct. Sorry it is difficult to explain, quantum mechanics (especially nontraditional interpretations like Everett's) are hard to do without using complex math.

I like this answer, and is kind of my intuitive understanding of this. The comparison to fair coin tosses is perfect. Perhaps we as conscious agents that experience continuity of self are biased to interpret MWI as having multiple "timelines". But your metaphor of frames that connect is a much more accurate model. And extremely anomalous quantum events are SO astronomically improbable it doesn't really make sense to think about feasibly happening to us.

This answer is technically incorrect.  There is no "different universe" "near" "an extremely unlikely one", nor do world-spaces collapse into each other.  Every series of spin up/clown is equally likely/unlikely, the only-up universe is no more improbable than one with the sequence dudddddduuuduuuuuud etc.  In MWI ALL of them exist, and no none of them collapse into each other, they each continue in parallel forever after they diverge.

@Dcleve I'm using an extremely-simplified version of the MWI where all of those things are true, primarily because from a philosophical standpoint the actual MWI gives no actual predictive power. Under the full MWI, if you assume that every sequence is equally likely to exist in the Universe that we "exist" in, then you could argue that the MWI supports literally anything happening - regular QM, all ups after a certain point, etc - because there exists a Universe where that would be the case and there is no way to distinguish between that Universe and any other except by awaiting observation.

Your comment is fine, but this paragraph of your answer is not:  " Timelines that string together increasingly-improbable events [...] require that there be no significantly-more-probable timelines "near" it in world space, [....] reality diverts to another more-probable one."  This is an incorrect description of the MWI worlds, the possibility of a world merging into another, and the role of probability in MWI.    NO this is not a "simplified version MWI", it is something else entirely.

You asked a lot of different things, so I'll just try to focus on one:

My main query is this: If every possible world exists, and quantum probability simply emerges from the abundance or perhaps density of worlds according to the properties of the wave function/Schrödinger's equation, then there are still real worlds in which very unlikely events happen. For example, there is a world where every Stern-Gerlach experiment reads every spin of every particle in the same direction.

Yes. If you like to think of it as "quantum coin flips", there's a very small but non zero chance of ending up in a world where the quantum coin flipped 100, 1000, 100000 heads in a row, so to speak. And if many worlds is correct, there is someone experiencing that truth.
And, in a vanishingly small number of worlds, the quantum coin flips luck is so extreme that quantum mechanics itself is not as obvious as it is in most other worlds.

Sean Caroll argues that MWI is what one gets if one throws out probabilities, and just uses the Schrodinger equation.  This is not actually the case, because one must also add in the Born rule, which has probabilities embedded in it, or else one cannot make valid predictions of our observed QM outcomes.
There have been various attempts to derive the Born rule from MWI assumptions, but they run into a problem in that they assume one is in a perspective OUTSIDE the MWs, and can sum them up probabilistically.  Carroll advocates for that here: https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2012/04/16/quantum-mechanics-and-decision-theory/ However, his assumption of circumstance weighting, IS itself to interject probability into the process.  Each option in MWI exists, and spawns an actual infinite of successive sub-universes. Including events which rely upon a 10^-600 improbable quantum interaction.  Such events have equally infinite numbers of spawned universes to events which have a 0.99999999999999999999999 probability of occurrence under the Born rule.  Carroll's decision theory logic presumes a weighted summing of probabilities across these actual infinities (as actual infinities, differential weighting based on probabilities is invalid), which is not actually consistent with MWI's math and the decorrelation of these infinite universes.
Here Less Wrong argues that Carroll's approach is just to assume Pilot Wave Theory, which is also known as Bohmian Mechanics https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/7nJt3hkQg9uSEta6M/demystifying-born-s-rule.  This is because Carroll's "summing across probabilities" is to deny the decoherence that MWI presumes.  Pilot wave theory IS deterministic, like the Schrodinger equation is, and unlike MWI.  Note that Bohmian Mechanics is an actually different theory than QM, and makes different predictions, and the tests are trending strongly against Bohm:  https://settheory.net/Bohm  So adopting Bohm has a downside too.
The general consensus is that MWI DOES require more than just the Schrodinger equation, one must also add in an unjustified Born Rule (which has embedded probabilities), else one cannot match actual test results.
The Born Rule is what creates a virtual bandwidth, or frequency space for the worlds of MWI.  But it really is between difficult to impossible to justify from MWI assumptions, and is not consistent with the MWI world trees each being an actual infinite.
Once one starts speculating based on outcomes being actual infinites, then one ends up with very incompatible predictions about the range of potential world-spaces, and in particular one loses any useful concept of causation in MWI.  My summary is that I could complete this answer, abandon it and spend the day playing video games, or walk next door to where the neighbor dog is barking, and kill the dog and the neighbors.  All are possible outcomes in MWI, all are actual infinites, and one cannot predict which of these paths one's experienced universe may take from this moment forward.
Well, fortunately in my experienced universe, I completed the post! ;->

I'm going to describe what the MWI actually claims before answering your question.
In some situations if you take a single particle and put it in a situation where it could go down multiple paths and then bring those paths back together, the result of the experiment depends on what would happen on all of the possible paths. But if you measure where the particle is you will only ever see it on one of the possible paths. This effect is called quantum interference. Since the result of the experiment depends on what happens along all of the possible paths and this can't happen unless something is actually propagating through all those paths. That thing, whatever it is, acts just like the particle you can see: it is blocked by anything that blocks the particle and affected by anything that affects the particle. It is just like the particle you can see except that you don't detect it when you do a measurement but if it is being blocked by a detector it must be setting the detector off so there must be a version of the detector we don't see and a computer recording data from the detector and so on: there must be whole universes that we don't see. The MWI is motivated by trying to explain the results of single particle interference experiments and many other kinds of quantum experiments, not solely, or even primarily, by some wonky theoretical exercise.
Reality as described by quantum theory's equations of motion without any modifications, also describes a system as existing in multiple versions. The reason why we see only one version is that if you interact with an interfering system and produce a record, that interaction will suppress interference: this effect is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
Decoherence causes the different versions of the systems you see around you to form layers that are autonomous from one another each of which acts approximately like the universe as described by classical physics for the objects you see in everyday life:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
In this context reality is often called the multiverse. A universe in the MWI is a structure in the multiverse in which information is copied:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
There is always a non-zero amount of interference going on: interference explains why the electrons in the atoms in your body don't fall into the nucleus. So in practice below a certain scale depending on your tolerance for interference the parallel universe approximation breaks down and so there is only a finite number of universes in any finite region of space and time.
There is a rule for calculating the probability of a particular outcome in quantum theory called the Born rule. The Born rule numbers don't act like probabilities in interference experiments: they only act like probabilities under decoherence. So you can only attach probabilities to versions of a system that don't interfere because of decoherence. The Born rule have been explained in the MWI in a couple of different ways
https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2718
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405161
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906015
There will be universes in which unlikely events happen. You ask:

Does this thought experiment make sense in Everettian Many-Worlds? If so, what does it mean? Could that mean we should not trust our theories of the world as strong as we do?

As explained by Karl Popper, scientific knowledge is created by noticing problems with existing theories, proposing solutions to these problems and then criticising the solutions until only one is left at which point you have solved the problem. For more detail see the Popper readings here:
https://fallibleideas.com/books#popper
When considering whether to use a theory you should consider whether there is a criticism of using it in that context rather than trusting it:
https://criticalfallibilism.com/introduction-to-critical-fallibilism/
The MWI claims you should expect the probabilities of results to be given by the Born rule so if you don't that constitutes a problem for the MWI
https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02048
As a result in some universes you would mistakenly think quantum theory is wrong. But you could make such a mistake for other reasons such as equipment malfunction or adopting bad philosophy.
The bad philosophy issue is very common since many physicists try to deny that quantum theory implies the existence of the multiverse without giving any alternative explanation claiming that this is unnecessary for making predictions: the Copenhagen and statistical interpretations of quantum theory. But a prediction is an explanation of what will happen in some particular circumstances and without such an explanation there is no standard by which you can judge whether you set up an experiment properly. So these interpretations are difficult or impossible to test. Some philosophers and physicists have adopted alternatives to quantum theory claiming there is only one universe, such as pilot wave theory and spontaneous collapse theory but these theories don't currently reproduce the predictions of quantum theory in the regime of relativity, which are the vast bulk of predictions of quantum theory
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
The possibility of misleading statistics is not the only or most important cause of errors.

If QM is complete the base theory implies many worlds OR superdeterminism. A lot of well known physicists flatly say QM is incomplete (or even incorrect) because at the very least it doesn’t agree with GR at extremely small scales/high energies, or that we simply can’t make that the completeness claim experimentally
